# Java. Hibernate Set<String> mapping, без сущности для справочной таблицы

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

Требуется помощь:

1. Есть сущность tbl_1 с Id и другими полями;
2. Есть вспомогательная таблица tbl_2, в ней храниться tbl_1.id и столбец с типом String;
3. Таблица tbl_2 справочная и не выделена в сущность. По факту там хранится перечень ассоциированных  слов;
4. Есть сущность с mapping на tbl_1. Там `Set<String> words`;
5. Как организовать такой мапинг в hibernate в свойство типа `Set<String>`.

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@XmlRootElement
public class Book {

    private UUID id;
    private Set<String> indexWords = new HashSet<>();

    public Book() {
    }

    @Id
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = String.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id")
    @JoinTable(name = "index_word", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "word")})
    @XmlElement
    public Set<String> getIndexWords() {
        return indexWords;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setIndexWords(Set<String> indexWords) {
        this.indexWords = indexWords;
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте классы, которые у вас уже есть в системе, либо примеры таблиц.

Comment: 1 класс, 2 таблицы. Код класса в вопросе.